# SQL failing to add value from previous row into the next

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to add the value of the previous row to the current row into the column cumulative

```
Select 
    Ddate as Date, etype, Reference, linkacc as ContraAcc,
    Description,
    sum(case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) as Debits,
    sum(case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) as Credits,
    sum(amount) as Cumulative
from
    dbo.vw_LT
where
    accnumber ='8400000' 
    and [DDate] between '2016-04-01 00:00:00' and '2016-04-30 00:00:00'
    and [DataSource] = 'PAS11CEDCRE17'
group by 
    Ddate, etype, Reference, linkacc, Description, Amount
```

Output(what i am getting):

```
Date        Reference   ContraAcc   Description Debits  Credits Cumulative 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-04-01     CC007    8000000     D/CC007      0      -39.19    -39.19
2016-04-01     CC007    8000000     D/CC007     1117.09     0     1117.09
2016-04-01     CC009    8000000     CC009       2600        0       2600
```

in the cumulative column should like below(what i need):

```
Date        Reference   ContraAcc   Description Debits  Credits Cumulative 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-04-01     CC007    8000000     D/CC007      0      -39.19    -39.19
2016-04-01     CC007    8000000     D/CC007     1117.09     0     1077.9
2016-04-01     CC009    8000000     CC009       2600        0     3677.9
```

Comment: you should post some sampled data and a expected result as your question is not clear.  Also tag your rdbms (oracle, mysql, sql-server) as answers will differ greatly.  Your query above has no mechanism that would be aware of other rows so their would be no running or cumulative totals

Comment: i have added the sample data

Comment: I don't understand what "in the cumulative column row two must be -39.19 + 1117.09 and so on" means - can you reword that to be clearer please? Is the output you posted what you currently get, or what you want?

Comment: i have put in the desired output

Answer (score 1):

Before we delve into the solution, let me tell you that if you are using SQL Server version more than 2012, there are [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh231256.aspx) and [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh213125.aspx), which can help you to solve this.

I am not giving you an exact query to solve your problem (as we dont know what your primary key for that table is), but you can get the idea by seeing the below example

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    accountNumber   VARCHAR(50)
    ,dt             DATETIME
    ,TransactedAmt  BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('0001','7/20/2016',1000)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('0001','7/21/2016',-1000)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('0001','7/22/2016',2000)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('0002','7/20/2016',500)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('0002','7/21/2016',-500)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('0002','7/22/2016',2000)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by accountNumber order by dt) as RN, * 
    FROM @t
),CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT *,TransactedAmt As TotalBalance
    FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
    UNION
    SELECT T1.*,T1.TransactedAmt + T0.TransactedAmt as TotalBalance
    FROM CTE T1
    JOIN CTE    T0
    ON  T1.accountNumber = T0.accountNumber
    AND T1.RN = T0.RN+1
    AND T1.RN > 1
)
select * from CTE1 order by AccountNumber
```

Comment: sorry i have tried the above and failed, please assist

Comment: With the give data I cannot understand if you want to add the rows indefinetly, i.e. do you want to add all the rows irrespective of Date, reference, contra account and all.. or the cummulative sum should stop once one of these changes

Comment: yes thank you for speedy response, it should add the rows indefinetly, irrespective of Date, reference, contra account and all.